# Read Timezoneinfo from windows registry (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, timezone, registry

I am trying to read the TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION struct from windows registry with the following code:

```
void GetTimeZoneInfo(){
    TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION tz = {0}; 
    TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION tz_data={0};
    char *keyname="TZI";
    DWORD size = sizeof(tz_data);
    HKEY hk = NULL;
    char *zone_key = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Time Zones\\Central Standard Time";
    if ((RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, zone_key, 0, KEY_READ, &hk) == ERROR_SUCCESS))
    {
        if(RegQueryValueExA(hk, keyname, NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE) &tz_data, &size) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        
        {    /*Control enters here*/
             /*Read the data*/
             cout<<"Successful in retrieving the value"<<endl;
            tz.Bias = tz_data.Bias;
            tz.DaylightBias = tz_data.DaylightBias;
            tz.DaylightDate = tz_data.DaylightDate;
            tz.StandardBias = tz_data.StandardBias;
            tz.StandardDate = tz_data.StandardDate;
        }
        else{ cout<<"Failure in retrieving the value"<<endl;}
    }
    else { cout<<"RegOpenKey Failure!"<<endl;}
}
```

It sets all to zero value, but don't see any error on running RegOpenKeyExA and RegQueryValueExA.
TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION is stored in registry as type: REG_BINARY

Is this the right way to read from registry?

Comment: How do you know that the function calls doesn't fail? You don't do anything if they fail (no output or message box telling about the errors).

Comment: Verified in debug mode. Updated the example

Answer (score 2):

According to [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/ns-timezoneapi-time_zone_information) TZI key contains the following time zone information:

```
typedef struct _REG_TZI_FORMAT
{
    LONG Bias;
    LONG StandardBias;
    LONG DaylightBias;
    SYSTEMTIME StandardDate;
    SYSTEMTIME DaylightDate;
} REG_TZI_FORMAT;
```

You are reading to a wrong struct - TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- In most cases you should be using the [`DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/ns-timezoneapi-dynamic_time_zone_information) structure, as it supports the full range of data that is in the registry.  Most of the Win32 time zone functions have alternative versions that work with the dynamic structures.
- You don't need to load the information from the registry yourself.  Instead, use [`EnumDynamicTimeZoneInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-enumdynamictimezoneinformation).  Enumerate them until the `TimeZoneKeyName` matches the one you are looking for.
- As [nevilad pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66087038/read-timezoneinfo-from-windows-registry-c/66087445#66087445), the `TZI` entries in the registry data aligns with `_REG_TZI_FORMAT`, which is slightly different than `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` structure.  (But again, you don't need to read from the registry yourself.
  )